# Render multiple images simultaneously in blender from multple cameras

Tags: rendering, camera

If I have 2 cameras in my scene, and I want to render images from both the cameras simultaneously and not one after the other, is that possible ?

One alternate option I was thinking of doing was open two blend files and render image from one camera in each blend file simultaneously. But my doubt is can it be done in the same blend file?

Comment: why the need to be simultaneous? the render time will be double anyway...?

Comment: I am trying to create renders of an object from 6 different views, and I am doing it for many objects. I am using a script. Was thinking of ways in which in can fast forward the process. Just checking if we can do it this way

Comment: 6 custom views, not from the 6 standard axis like a cubic environment map, I suppose?

Comment: @Sum-Al Did you find any solutions for this?